# React PLX Element yields " Maximum update depth exceeded" error

Tags: reactjs, parallax

I installed react-plx like so:  `npm install --save react-plx`

Here is the link to the module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-plx

I followed the example on the page above, and defined these variables under "render":

```
render() {
    const exampleParallaxData = [
      {
        start: 100,
        duration: 400,
        easing: "ease",
        properties: [
          {
            startValue: 0,
            endValue: 250,
            property: "translateY"
          }
        ]
      }
    ];

    const styles = {
      width: 200,
      height: 100,
      lineHeight: "100px",
      textAlign: "center",
      borderRadius: 20,
      backgroundColor: "#34ba9c",
      color: "#fff",
      position: "absolute"
    };


    return (
        <div className="callToAction">
          <Plx parallaxData={exampleParallaxData} style={styles}>
            Hello
            <button className="draw">I am a button</button>
          </Plx>
        </div>
    );
      }
    }
```

Sometimes it works... but others I get this error:

```
dev-vendors.js:2057 Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
    at invariant (dev-vendors.js:2057)
    at requestWork (dev-vendors.js:46621)
    at scheduleWorkImpl (dev-vendors.js:46520)
    at scheduleWork (dev-vendors.js:46477)
    at Object.enqueueSetState (dev-vendors.js:42000)
    at Plx.Component.setState (dev-vendors.js:8044)
    at eval (Plx.js:704)
```

Is there any way for me to avoid this problem or does this mean I should not use the package?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example

```js
import React from 'react';
import Plx from 'react-plx';
class TestJS extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const exampleParallaxData = [
            {
                start: 100,
                duration: 400,
                easing: "ease",
                properties: [
                    {
                        startValue: 0,
                        endValue: 250,
                        property: "translateY"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];

        const styles = {
            width: 200,
            height: 100,
            lineHeight: "100px",
            textAlign: "center",
            borderRadius: 20,
            backgroundColor: "#34ba9c",
            color: "#fff",
            position: "absolute"
        };

        return(
            <div className="callToAction">
                <Plx parallaxData={exampleParallaxData} style={styles}>
                    Hello
                    <button className="draw">I am a button</button>
                </Plx>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TestJS;
```

Comment: Is there something different between my example and this one? So, the example I used does show what is expected most of the time, but sometimes it throws the error above. I am looking for why that error might be thrown. (Let me know if missed it in your answer!)

Comment: I just copied your example. Have you imported the package at the top?
Restart the application once and test it. There is no difference in the example which I shared you and your code.